# Loopback application complains of missing license file

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I have installed strongloop in my machine and are trying to explore basic features of strongloop.

After creating a loop back application, when I try to access 'arc composer' using slc command "slc arc", I am getting the below error;

arc error
[image]

I am unable to find such 'licenses.json' file in my machine.

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you tell us how you created your project? Anyhow, a little reset won't harm. So, maybe recreate but this time using their application https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Application-generator.html